# Do we need both [difficulty] and [difficulty-class]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed we have two tags which are pretty similar:

- [difficulty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficulty)

  > Use this tag when asking about the target numbers rolls are trying to achieve, in systems which call them "difficulties." (d20 System questions should be tagged [difficulty-class].)
- [difficulty-class](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficulty-class)

  > Use this tag when asking about the target numbers rolls are trying to achieve, in systems which calls that the "difficulty class."

They seem to be basically the same concept, except that it instructs us to use a very slightly different name for systems which give that same fundamental concept a very slightly different name. I consider it noteworthy that the [difficulty] has [five questions tagged D&D 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difficulty+dnd-5e) against instruction.

Should we make these tags synonyms, or keep them separate (and maybe do some retagging)?

Comment: Previous meta on this topic: [What should the dc tag be called?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5134/15469). Also relevant context: [There's no tag for DC or difficulty class](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5121/15469).

Answer (score -1):

#### Depending on the game system, "difficulty" and "difficulty-class" may not be synonyms

[DC/Difficulty Class is a thing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102633/22566).

[Some game systems use difficulty all by itself](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5138/22566).

Maybe we should leave well enough alone.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out, in support of this answer, that *none* of the five questions mentioned in the OP are using the [tag:difficulty] tag to mean the concept under discussion. They're all about "encounter-difficulty", not "target number on a die roll difficulty".

Comment: @Miniman Hmm, more thinking needed.

Comment: It proves your point about the nebulousness of "difficulty", at least.

Comment: @Miniman We can afford to be patient on arriving at an answer, none of this has an impact on flight safety.